# Why are closures broken within exec?

Tags: python, closures, exec

In Python 2.6,

```
>>> exec "print (lambda: a)()" in dict(a=2), {}
2
>>> exec "print (lambda: a)()" in globals(), {'a': 2}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
>>> exec "print (lambda: a).__closure__" in globals(), {'a': 2}
None
```

I expected it to print `2` twice, and then print a tuple with a single `cell`. It is the same situation in 3.1. What's going on?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you pass a string to `exec` or `eval`, it compiles that string to a code object before considering globals or locals. So when you say:

```
eval('lambda: a', ...)
```

it means:

```
eval(compile('lambda: a', '<stdin>', 'eval'), ...)
```

There's no way for `compile` to know that `a` is a freevar, so it compiles it to a global reference:

```
>>> c= compile('lambda: a', '<stdin>', 'eval')
>>> c.co_consts[0]
<code object <lambda> at 0x7f36577330a8, file "<stdin>", line 1>
>>> dis.dis(c.co_consts[0])
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Therefore to make it work you have to put `a` in the globals and not the locals.

Yeah, it's a bit dodgy. But then that's `exec` and `eval` for you I suppose... they're not supposed to be nice.

Comment: +1. I've been refreshing this thread once every minute since it was posted to find out the answer to this one. Thanks to you I am now free to leave my puter for a while and go out and enjoy the sun. Thank you! ;)

Comment: To make closures work with exec, I provide a trick in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72340953/9758790). In short, wrap the original codes that define a function with a temp helper fucntion, so that the `compile` can recognize freevar like `a`.

Comment: Is the new `closure` parameter to `exec()` in 3.11 related to solving this? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75941073/give-an-example-explanation-of-the-closure-parameter-of-the-exec-function